# "Run" will build and launch config incorrectly

Tags: delphi

I am using Delphi XE3. In my project group, I have two projects, Project1 and Project2, each has Debug and Release configurations. For Project1, there is a definition _TEST.

I then create a build group which contains both Project1 and Project2. Each project’s Debug and Release configurations are also included.

Then when I use “Build the current build group” button to build all configurations for both Project1 and Project2, then after the build, if I use “Run” to debug Project1, I will find the launched version is an incorrect version(built without _TEST definition).

However, if I build the Debug configuration of the Project1 individually, not through the Build Group, then after the build, if I use “Run” to debug Project1, I will find the launched version is a correct version(built with _TEST definition).

Moreover, if I launch Project1.exe directly in Windows, instead of using “Run” or “Run without debugging”, then the launched version is always a correct version(built with _TEST definition).

What is the problem?

Comment: Don't store two application projects in same group. It is buggy as hell.

Comment: These two projects share the same code base, the only difference is that Project1 has a definition _TEST. That is the reason why I put them into a project group.

Comment: And that is exactly what is broken in Delphi. It messes up defines while compiling when it compiles/builds multiple exe files in a row which happens when you say build all, and sometimes when you just use "Run" on one project it will also build others.

Comment: In such a case, should I put the project with different definitions in different groups, or in a same group but built individually?

Comment: First option would be better. If you keep them in same project group individual builds work fine, but you have to remember doing build and run actions separately. And even then sometimes when you run from the IDE, Delphi decides to build all and makes a mess.